# find control inside datalist using javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

find control inside datalist using javascript

Suppose in Datalist 2 Control is Present like label1 label2 and linkbutton
I want to access value of label1 when click on linkbutton by using javascript
how to find control on button click inside the datalist using javascript

Comment: i have update my answer check this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' runat="server"
            ID="Label1" />
        <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' runat="server"
            ID="lblText" />
        <input type="button" id="btn" runat="server" name="btn" value="Click" onclick="btnClick(this);" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Add Script on you page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClick(obj) {
        var tr = getParentRow(obj);
        var datalist = document.getElementById('<%=dlData.ClientID%>');
        var txtbox = datalist.getElementsByTagName("lblText");
        var Id = datalist.rows[tr.rowIndex].cells[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        var Name = datalist.rows[tr.rowIndex].cells[0].childNodes[3].innerHTML;
    }
    function getParentRow(obj) {
        while (obj.tagName != "TR") {
            if (isFireFox()) {
                obj = obj.parentNode;
            }
            else {
                obj = obj.parentElement;
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    function isFireFox() {
        return navigator.appName == "Netscape";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: in jquery $('txtbox').click(function(){ alert("hello"); }); is it correct?

Comment: no because your selector is wrong? use `#txtbox` if `textbox` is id of your control or `.txtbox` if your control's class is `txtbox`.

Comment: i have upodate my answer.